# Import PEAR Projects to Career Profile

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, jobs

It would be a very useful idea to be able to import PEAR projects that somebody maintains to their careers.stackoverflow.com profile. Most of what is required could be gleaned from the user specific rss profile URL; this takes the form of https://pear.php.net/feeds/user_{username}.rss

Answer (score 2):

In the case of the ‘Open Source’ and ‘Apps & Software’ sections, you can simply add a URL and we scrape it for info as best we can. Of course it’s all editable before adding to your profile.

(We don’t explicitly support rubygems or npm either, the idea is the same.)

As a practical matter, most folks will link over to the repository on GitHub or Bitbucket, etc. The information tends to be richer than on the package sites.